# Why \xF3 is not recognized as UTF-8

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, padrino

I have this hash:

```
a={"topic_id"=>60693, "urlkey"=>"innovacion", "name"=>"Innovaci\xF3n"}
```

and I am trying to save it to MongoDB using Mongoid, when I get this error:

```
BSON::InvalidStringEncoding: String not valid UTF-8
```

I am then trying to `gsub` it:

```
a["name"].gsub(/\xF3/,"o")
```

and I get: `SyntaxError: (pry):12: too short escaped multibyte character: /\xF3/`

I have added a magic comment at the beginning of my model file:`# encoding: UTF-8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hexidecimal 0xF3 by itself is *not* valid UTF-8.  Values greater than 0x7F are all multi-byte characters.  What makes you think it should be UTF-8?

You can read up on the allowable sequences here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

If you need to force the ruby string to assume an encoding that allows arbitrary byte sequences, you can force it to binary:

```
str.force_encoding("BINARY")
```

With a binary encoding, `#gsub` and other string operations that rely on valid encodings will work on a byte-by-byte basis, instead of a character-by-character basis.

Comment: I think mongo / bson will still reject the invalid utf8 though

Comment: As @FrederickCheung guessed, it is rejected by mongo indeed. However, I have come up with this: ```a.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(0xF3.chr," ")``` which works fine. Nevertheless, I can not find a way to express it with Regexp, as I can not use a Method after the expression: ```a.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(/0x....?/.chr,"")``` throws an error: ```NoMethodError: undefined method `chr' for /0x....?/:Regexp```

Comment: For the record, I have managed to overcome the issue of the invalid UTF-8 char by ```unpack("C*").pack("U*")``` the string in question...